# java (android) create JSONObject from scratch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to do something like:

```
public static final JSONObject MYOBJ = new JSONObject().put("value", "expression");
```

but eclipse get's mad and says there's an error on the line even though the tool tip shows `No solutions available`

I've tried changing `JSONObject` to type `String` and still the same prob. I'm shying away from hash maps and would really like to use JSON.

** EDIT - code location **

```
package ...

import ...

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static final JSONObject MYOBJ = new JSONObject().put("value", "expression");

    ... // onCreate etc
}
```

Comment: Where do you exactly put this statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it seems the JSONObject has a checked exception that must be handled. Try this

```
public static final JSONObject MYOBJ = new JSONObject(){
    {
        try {
            put("value", "expression");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That's a pain, seems like a runtime exception would have been a better choice.

Comment: Fortunately it's not `final` so a delegate class that throws an RTE is diable :)

Answer (score 2):

The result of put() is an Object.
Do it in two lines and all is well.

```
public static final JSONObject MYOBJ = new JSONObject();
static {
  MYOBJ.put("value", "expression");
}
```

Note that the static final doesn't prevent the object from being changed, just that the original reference MYOBJ will always be the same object.

Edit:
Ah, I was probably using a different flavor of the JSON library. Nonetheless, the above approach will probably work nicely. If the types all match, add some more parens to the original line.

Comment: For which JSONObject? According to this it's a JSONObject http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: Pretty sure it's the exception ;)

Comment: @Jackson The `static` doesn't have anything to do with that; `final` means the reference won't be changed once assigned, `static` means it's a class variable (as opposed to instance variable).

Comment: @Dave I suppose I addressed the usage wrong, but either way I gave a +1 in regards to line 2-4.

Comment: @Jackson Oh, that; I see. Yep, static initialization block.

Comment: static { } blocks are definitely NOT my favorite thing!